# Análisis de mediación con lavaan

Tags: r

Necesito probar dos mediaciones simultáneamente con lavaan, pero he tenido problemas para definir el modelo. Cuando ejecuto el script, los valores para la variable `vintri` y `vextri` son muy similares, lo que me hace pensar que no he definido correctamente los efectos directos e indirectos.
Les dejo mi código más abajo.

```
model1<- ' 
#MODELO DE MEDIDA# 
sl =~ sl_superv + sl_amb + sl_prest + sl_intri + sl_part
Expid =~ ae1+ae6+ae11  
Auto =~ ae3+ae8+ae13
Smedio =~ ae4+ae9+ae14
Pos =~ ae5+ae10+ae15
#MODELO ESTRUCTURAL# 
vintri ~ Expid+Auto+Smedio+Pos
vextri ~ Expid+Auto+Smedio+Pos
sl ~ a* vintri
sl ~ a* vextri
ip ~ b* sl 
ip ~ Expid+Auto+Smedio+Pos
ip ~ c* vintri
ip ~ c* vextri
#COVARIANZAS
vintri ~~ vextri
Expid ~~ Auto
Expid ~~ Smedio
Expid ~~ Pos
Auto ~~ Smedio
Auto ~~ Pos
Smedio ~~ Pos
#EFECTOS INDIRECTOS Y TOTALES 
ab := a*b
total := c + (a*b)
'
#AJUSTE
fit1<- sem(model1, 
       data=var.model,
       estimator= "WLSMV")

summary(fit1, 
     fit.measures= TRUE,
     standardized= TRUE,
     rsquare= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

después de algunos días buscando una solución, finalmente la encontré. El problema era que configuré los paths como iguales

```
sl ~ a* vintri
sl ~ a* vextri
ip ~ c* vintri
ip ~ c* vextri
```

La solución fue asignar una letra distinta a cada path. De esta forma:

```
sl ~ a* vintri
sl ~ b* vextri
ip ~ c* vintri
ip ~ d* vextri
```